# Codeigniter Pagination cannot initialize

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Here is the controller ....

```
public function viewdeals (){


  $this ->load-> model ('model_dealview');
  if (  $q1 = $this-> model_dealview-> getdeals()){

      $this->load->library('pagination');

      $config['base_url'] = 'formalert/viewdeals';
      $config['total_rows'] = 40;
      $config['per_page'] = 5;

      $this->pagination->initialize($config);
      $q1['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
      $this -> load -> view ('view_deals', $q1);


 }
```

The problem is that whenever I try to run this with pagination ... i get this error

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Contoller_name::$pagination

Fatal error: Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object in
C:\wamp\www\ci\application\controllers\controllerfile_name.php on line 108
```

Everything works fine without pagination ...

I have tried loading library in cofig file ... done pretty much everything .. even copied code from the internet that work for other people .. Need help! ...

Please note its not identifying the property `$pagination` ... so other small problems in teh code won't matter.

Comment: can it be that you need to specify your full pagination url not just the controller and the method names?

Comment: doesnt matter ...  i canged it to base_url().'formalert/viewdeals';

Comment: did the var_dump($config);exit; before the error .. got this 

array (size=3)
  'base_url' => string 'http://localhost/ci/formalert/viewdeals' (length=39)
  'total_rows' => int 40
  'per_page' => int 5

its something deeper i guess. (or a stupid blunder).

Comment: Ok. take a look [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) and see what they are saying about the **base_url** for pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem solved. You need to autoload the pagination library... just loading it in the function will not do.